# C++: Classes and Header Files

Tags: c++, class

In my adventures in learning C++, I am having trouble linking classes and headers together! I *believe* this syntax is correct, however receive the error:

> undefined reference to 'foo::bar()'

Below is my code, I hope I converted it to foobarbazian correctly!:

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    foo baz;
    baz.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef __HEADER_H_INCLUDED__
#define __HEADER_H_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo {
    public:
        void bar();
};
#endif
```

baz.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void foo::bar () {
    cout << "Whose flow? Overflow!" << endl;

    return;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What command did you use to compile and link the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not including your `baz.cpp` file when compiling. You need to include all the source files when compiling. Example:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp baz.cpp
```

After you do that you will get another error of:

> baz.cpp: In member function ‘void foo::bar()’: baz.cpp:6:12: error:
>
> return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void'

because you are trying to return a value to a `void` function.
Remove the `return true;` statement from your `foo::bar()` function definition.

Comment: Ah! the return true was an error on my translating the code (was initially a bool, but changed to a void for clarity)

Comment: I am using the Code::Blocks IDE -- I'll look up how to include all the files in the source directory! Thank you!